# Visio 2013 - using linked data for shape labels

Tags: label, visio

I've seen how easy it is to link data to shapes in Visio 2013, but what I want to do is to use the data from some of the fields as the text of the shape's label.

I want to use part of one field and the whole of another in a formatted string. I've not been able to see anywhere how to write **any** field content to the label, let alone do any kind of transformations also.

The label should be formatted as "x [y]" where 'x' is the first line of field "Description" (up to the first CRLF if there is one) and 'y is the content of the "Transport" field.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert Field, then enter a custom formula using Visio's string operations.

I believe the following custom formula will do what you as above:

`IFERROR(LEFT(prop.description, find(char(13), Prop.Description) - 1)), prop.description) & " [" & Prop.Transport & "]"`

Comment: Hi,

This really helped thanks. I ended up creating a view in the database which exposed the data in the format I needed (my SQL is much better than my Visio skills) and used the "Insert field" option.

Thanks for answering and giving me the perfect pointer I needed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mark do you have xsd for parsing visio 2013?